# Erro ao executar a função PASSWORD NO MYSQL SERVER ( ERRO 1064 SQL SYNTAX)

Tags: mysql

Erro ao executar a função `PASSWORD` NO MYSQL SERVE

Estou com o seguinte query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE login = 'FABIO' 
  AND pwd = PASSWORD('2018') 
LIMIT 0, 50000
```

Esta dando esse erro:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near

Comment: Veja o que FABIO esta entre aspas simples, password tambem tem de estar também.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo O password e função não pode esta entre aspa simples. A query esta correta.

Comment: Fabio, quando disse que a password tem de estar entre aspas simples foi uma dica. A query que esta chegando no banco não esta correta. Você tem de escrever algo tipo assim: "SELECT * from usuarios where login = 'FABIO' and pwd = '" + PASSWORD('2018') + "' LIMIT 0, 50000 "  para que a query que chegar ao banco chegue corretamente.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo no caso, a concatenação não é necessária visto que a função é nativa do MySQL. Eu creio que seria algum tipo de configuração errada no meu MySQL Server, pois em outro servidor uma query idêntica à essa funciona e traz o resultado correto.

Comment: Digamos que a funcão PASSWORD esteja retornando 123. Faça o select assim: SELECT * from usuarios where login = 'FABIO' and pwd = '123' LIMIT 0, 50000

Comment: @Reginaldo funciona ai trás os resultados. O problema esta quando coloco a função PASSWORD.

Comment: Você tem de montar seu select de modo que coloque as aspas no retorno da função. Ou fazer a função já retornar o valor entre aspas.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo como informado anteriormente,  no caso, a concatenação não é necessária visto que a função é nativa do MySQL. Eu creio que seria algum tipo de configuração errada no meu MySQL Server, pois em outro servidor uma query idêntica à essa funciona e traz o resultado correto.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo depois da uma olhada na resposta do Guilherme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabio, dê uma olhada neste link:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password

Veja qual a sua versão do MySQL Server, pois a partir da 8.0.11 esta função não está mais disponível.

Em outra versão de MySQL sua query funcionaria perfeitamente.

Comment: Isso mesmo Guilherme, pena que parou de usar vou começar usar outra função obrigado.